# Finding River Lots in Alberta, Saskatchewan and Manitoba using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geolocation, canada, geocoding, township-range-section

I have to border farmlands in Canada (Alberta, Saskatchewan and Manitoba). Usually they give input in the form of **DLS** like **SE-9-56-22-W4**.So I use https://locator.scadalink.com/dls2latlng.html to find location and border farmlands.(like in Screenshot below)[image: Border]

Each Section has 640 Acres,Half 320 Acres and Quarter 160 Acres.

Currently I am facing issues, I recieved input as **RiverLots** like **RL-8-55-22-W4**. I don't know how to find these RiverLot location.

I have tried Scadalink Locator and LegalLandConverter but no use.

How do I find and border RiverLots using QGIS?

Comment: I guess you have to look it up at https://web22.gov.mb.ca/mao/public/search_select.aspx or similar locators for other provinces. QGIS has no such locators inside.

Comment: This site is for manitoba, and it does not have any option to find river lots. yes have to look for locators!